# Alternate Laravel Query

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

What is the alternate query in Laravel for the following query?

```
SELECT t1.siteName, COALESCE(t2.fee, 0) FROM sites t1
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT site_id, sum(fee) as fee
    FROM tickets
    WHERE ticketdate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-03-31'
    GROUP BY site_id
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.site_id
ORDER BY t2.fee DESC
```

Comment: Do you have any models created like Sites or Tickets? Laravel queries could either be raw Queries against the Database or the use of Eloquent (which needs to have models being created).

Comment: We need to show all sites name and their total fee in a given period, when total fee is 0 against any site, it shows 0. we have correct sql query for it, but we need to implement this query in Laravel. So, we need alternate query in laravel for given below query:

Tables

sites(id, siteName, created_at, updated_at)
tickets(id, site_id, fee, ticketdate, created_at, updated_at)

Models:
Site, Ticket

Answer (score 0):

```
We need to show all sites name and their total fee in a given period, when total fee is 0 against any site, it shows 0. we have correct sql query for it, but we need to implement this query in Laravel. So, we need alternate query in laravel for given below query:

Tables:
sites(id, siteName, created_at, updated_at)
tickets(id, site_id, fee, ticketdate, created_at, updated_at)

Models:
Site, Ticket
```